# Google Play Service works with Facebook Canvas Unity3d

Tags: facebook, unity-game-engine, google-play-services, facebook-canvas

Hii I am unity3d developer.

I want to publish my game on facebook. for that i need to make facebook canvas settings.

But i have leaderboard and achievement of google play service available in my game. I want to know will it work with facebook canvas ?

Thanks,
Hope you all understand my point.

Comment: Isn’t that something you could just try and see …?

Comment: But if anybody have experienced same thing then they can just share. @CBroe

Answer (score 1):

It will not work.

GooglePlayServices are intended for Android use.

This is like expecting GooglePlayServices to work when you deploy to iOS and want to use GameCenter.